# Downloading files from read protected directory using wget

Tags: permissions, wget

I'm trying to download some files that I assume are in a read-protected directory as pointing `wget` to that directory or accessing it through the browser returns a `403` error. I can however access individual files within the directory both from `wget` and the browser. My question is if there are any ways to download all the files from that directory? I would usually do this by passing the `-r -np` options to `wget` along with that directory, but as stated that returns a `403` error.

Comment: @heynnema: I would say that qualifies as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 403 error means you don't have permission to read at the directory level, only the file level. If this is a git or ppa, they usually provide a download link for all of the files... check the web site.

Comment: Hmm. While this isn't the case with my situation this is the best answer in the general case. Thank you!